# User pool client {id}does not exist

Tags: php, amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

Here is my code:

```
 use Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\CognitoIdentityProviderClient;

$args = [ 
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'valid',
        'secret' => 'valid',
    ],
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',

    'app_client_id' => 'valid',
    'app_client_secret' => 'valid',
    'user_pool_id' => 'valid',
];

$email = 'test32@test.com';

$client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient($args);
$hash_key = cognitoSecretHash($email);

$login =  $client->adminInitiateAuth([
            'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            'AuthParameters' => [
                'Username' => $email,
                'Password' => '12345678',
                'SecretHash' => $hash_key,
            ],
            'ClientId' => 'valid',
            'UserPoolId' => 'valid',
        ]);

return $login;


 function cognitoSecretHash($username)
{
    $message = $username . 'app_client_id';

    $hash = hash_hmac(
        'sha256',
        $message,
        'app_client_secret',
        true
    );

    return base64_encode($hash);
}
```

Its give me this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\Exception\CognitoIdentityProviderException' with message 'Error executing "AdminInitiateAuth" on "https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client {id} does not exist."} ResourceNotFoundException (client): User pool client {id} does not exist. - {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client {id} does not exist."}' GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client {id} does not exist."} in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test\vend in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $login =  $client->adminInitiateAuth([
            'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            'AuthParameters' => [
                'USERNAME' => $email,
                'PASSWORD' => $password,
                'SECRET_HASH' => $hash_key,
            ],
            'ClientId' => $clientId,
            'UserPoolId' => $poolId,
        ]);
```

Comment: This is not helpful. What exactly did you determine to be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and just had to do an `amplify pull` - problem was out of sync project on different computers and `git pull` didn't cover the aws backend stuffs I think.